# How to color excel column ranges between AC to AE in c# code

Tags: c#, .net, excel, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to color a particular range of cells in exsisting excel using C# code.

Below is the code I tried but it throws an exception.Let me know how to proceed.

```
excelWorkSheet4.get_Range("AC", "AE").Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
```

Comment: By supplying more information?

Comment: what information you need in this ?

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer for this one below code works for any particular range after "Z"

```
excelWorkSheet4.get_Range("AC:AC", "AE:AE").Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
```